# Making a Movieclip which is under a mask clickable and respond to MouseEvents

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mouseevent, masking

This question is a follow up to the questions on link:
[Making a Movieclip which is set as mask clickable and respond to MouseEvents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832117/making-a-movieclip-which-is-set-as-mask-clickable-and-respond-to-mouseevents)

The structure of your layers that I have on stage looks like this:

- holder_mc

  - dragCanvas_mc
  - mask_mc
  - canvas_mc

dragCanvas_mc - used for panning puposes.

mask_mc  - Mask for canvas_mc

I am facing a problem now. I cannot get MouseEvents to be registered on the canvas_mc

This is required because I have to make drawings to the canvas

```
holder_mc.canvas_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,onStartDrawing);

function onStartDrawing(evt:MouseEvent)
{
    trace("Hello");
}
```

I cannot see Hello in output window. Any idea where I am wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does the structure exactly look like? which layers are nested which are on the same level? can you maybe show the code how you create all MCs?

Comment: `1st` - does your canvas_mc is an empty movie clip? if yes then you need to add some background where you would be able to click. `2nd` - does your dragCanvas_mc is overlaying the canvas_mc? if yes it shold not, because it will take all of the mouse event to it self.

Comment: Deleted answer, too early for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 'MovieClip A' is above 'MovieClip B' on the display list and 'MovieClip A' is 'mouseEnabled' then 'MovieClip B' will never receive the events "through" the top MovieClip.

In your case, the drag canvas is above, and is most likely attached to some mouse events. If this is the case, you need to handle the events with the top clip (drag canvas) and pass them through to the children, or the parent, holder_mc.

```
holder_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    // do normal clicky stuff for this object
    // then..
    //

    if(canvas_mc.hitTestPoint(mouseX, mouseY, false)) {
        // do clicky stuff for canvas mc
    }    

}
```

Some people might say use 'getObjectsUnderPoint' but there is a documented bug with it, so use hitTestPoint() http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestPoint%28%29

Answer (score 1):

It could be that your mask_mc is intercepting the mouse events. You can try this test to see who is firing the `MouseEvent.CLICK`.

```
holder_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,whoFiredTheEvent);

function whoFiredTheEvent(e:MouseEvent){
  trace(e.target.name + " fired the event");
}
```

If it is the mask_mc or some other movie clip you can set `mouseEnabled` to false for that movie clip and the `MouseEvent` will ignore it.